# how to pass object type of data form one page to another in flutter

Tags: flutter

my object class is type of **ReqDetailModel**  on button click we  have to pass object to another page
first page where we have one button

```
onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SendMessageScreen()));
              },
```

second page :

```
class SendMessageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SendMessageScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SendMessageScreen> createState() => _SendMessageScreenState();
}
```

I have get that object from previous page .

i am new in flutter i am getting error while passing object unable to get  pass object can any one please help me in this .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to the constructor of `SendMessageScreen` like

```
class SendMessageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final ReqDetailModel reqDetailModel; 
  const SendMessageScreen({super.key, required this.reqDetailModel});

  @override
  State<SendMessageScreen> createState() => _SendMessageScreenState();
}
```

And then pass it like

```
onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SendMessageScreen(reqDetailModel: theActualModel)));
          },
```

Comment: Thanks for answer  but reqDetailModel is actual object data what is reqDetailModel i want to know what we need to pass that is it key or what?